# Can you use java.swing and javafx for android development?

Tags: java, android, javafx

I dont really know a lot about about android development and i was wondering if it's possible to use java.swing and/or javafx for it.

Comment: Definitely not Swing.

Comment: No and even if you could you shouldn't.

**Specially not GridBagLayout**

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/) to develop [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) applications (not Swing applications) that are deployable on Android.  Refer to the [JavaFXPorts documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/) for more information.

You will need to make your own assessment of whether using JavaFXPorts is an appropriate approach for your application or if you are better off coding purely to the native Android SDK provided by Google or using another 3rd party development SDK such as Unity.  I will make no such recommendation here.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Androids java (Go) does not include the `java.swing` and the `javafx` packages.

Android does include it's own gui packages more specialised for it, so I don't see why you would even want swing or javafx.

Comment: Go is not "Androids java". Go is a separate programming language, without much to do with Android.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use Swing or JavaFX because Android has another type of architecture to render the views. Visit this official website to learn more about views in Android

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/overview.html

Hope it's helps.